# nodejs openpgp hashing algorithm to SHA256

Tags: node.js, sha256, openpgp

I managed to sign message with OpenPGP sign() function,but how can I change the hashing algorithm to SHA256?

```
    async function pgpSignMessage(privateKey,messageToSign,callback) { 
    const unsignedMessage = await openpgp.createCleartextMessage({ text: messageToSign }); 
    const cleartextMessage  = await openpgp.sign({
        message: unsignedMessage,  
        signingKeys: privateKey,    
    });
  
   console.log("pgpSignMessage cleartextMessage ",cleartextMessage );
    return callback(cleartextMessage  );
);
```

**ouput :**

```
pgpSignMessage cleartextMessage

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

This is a testing message

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
wsBzBAEBCgAGBQJjTOMPACEJEPjzUwweaxTJFiEEcJyNNiL/3PuC/Rze+PNT
DB5rFMnA2wf+OQV8+S1o12hrHgIOy362xHk7jk+bhUf2DzosyMIb5/FaP58a
Y2VxZUOMkYPFJeiJ9dO7z+25QjbUgbZz5ikExdPIIwmfY1BPX8jgWEQAniOD
ZZVg+pG2hALuZwzBchw+onvoPyyZLSNajkY4rA/wXexuAljWqWTpypoN51iQ
O/E4TN2FbAIQOq89tzS5MXhEAZe4bYHH4cUwsQiaIjA+2OjrspPJt+3/nosP
1f6k6wgZKuPDbyK6KKSqtb0tzFmIVkF+4+VF+vQFi7kx5utWn/nXOWO78tUV
s6dn23+GdJ5sLaFUT5vPDKux3dddErPOKEam/hJUe5VoO2LzeNO5Ww==
=KsDz

-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the [preferred hash algorithm](https://docs.openpgpjs.org/module-config.html#.preferredHashAlgorithm) at the generation of your keys?

Comment: the keys was generated with kleopatra (https://www.openpgp.org/software/kleopatra/) there is not setting for hash algorithm when creating key pair

Comment: Have you tried setting the preferred hash algorithm when you call the `sign()` function with the `config` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Having access to the `openpgp.js` sources (in this case it is latest `master` commit), and going down through the `sign()` function code, you'll occasionally get to this:

```js
export async function getPreferredHashAlgo(key, keyPacket, date = new Date(), userID = {}, config) {
  let hashAlgo = config.preferredHashAlgorithm;
  let prefAlgo = hashAlgo;
  if (key) {
    const primaryUser = await key.getPrimaryUser(date, userID, config);
    if (primaryUser.selfCertification.preferredHashAlgorithms) {
      [prefAlgo] = primaryUser.selfCertification.preferredHashAlgorithms;
      hashAlgo = crypto.hash.getHashByteLength(hashAlgo) <= crypto.hash.getHashByteLength(prefAlgo) ?
        prefAlgo : hashAlgo;
    }
  }
...
```

So, it would first pick value from the `config.preferredHashAlgorithm`. Then, if primary user's id certification contains preferred hash algorithms subpacket, and first value's hash length is longer then config's one, it will pick it up.

You may get more information about your key via `gpg --list-packets` command.

Comment: hi Nickolay, that for your answer, but sorry that I am new to this OpenPGP, I have downloaded Gpg4win and installed, but can't find option --list-packets, but I can find --list-keys, are they the same?

Comment: I have try to set the openpgp.config.preferredHashAlgorithm = openpgp.enums.hash.sha256 (8), and print out the value, but when I sign the message it still using SHA512, 

openpgp.config.preferredHashAlgorithm 8
openpgp.enums.hash.sha256 8
pgpSignMessage cleartextMessage  -----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA512

Comment: You should use commang-line GnuPG (gpg command) for that. Most likely your key has SHA512 as first preferred hash algorithm, and since it's size is larger then SHA256 openpgp.js uses it.